# what does "being of concern" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I can't understand the meaning of *concern* here:

> therefore a topic such as how to go about recording and preserving interview data is methodological, while interpretation and reliability of oral histories would be a theoretical topic, although one can hopefully see how the two often end up *being of concern* at the same time for researchers who are interviewing elderly musicians to learn about the musical past, for example.

Comment: "being important". See [*concern*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/concern): "5. countable noun - 
Someone's concerns are the things that they consider to be important."

Answer (score 1):

An "object of concern" is something which is of particular interest to someone.  "Being of concern" expresses this same idea in a gerund phrase which modifies "the two" -- which is to say, both "recording and preserving interview data" and "interpretation and reliability of oral histories".

In other words, the author is saying these two topics are both *of concern* to certain researchers.

There are of course more direct ways to say this, but your example is grammatical.